# processing data file when a flag file is created

Tags: bash, sunos

I have a data file, that when a flag file is created, the data file is encrypted. Here is an example of the data file name WSPGLOBAL.PAYMENTS.ISO20022_PAIN_01Ver3.66169592.xml   and the flag file name SendPaysource.66169592 . I want to be able to pass the numeric part of the flag file name and only gpg the corresponding data file with that numeric value in the name.

I currently have a working script that does the gpg based on wildcards, but there may be a possibility that there is a second data file that is not ready to be sent and doesnt have the flag file.

```
#!/bin/bash

. /pbapps/pbmis/apps/apps_st/appl/APPSpbmis_ennycebs02.env

if [ -e /misc/pbmis/output/SendPaysource.* ];
then
gpg --always-trust --no-tty -se --passphrase xxxxxxxxx -r xxxxx.xxxxx.com  /misc/pbmis/output/WSPGLOBAL.PAYMENTS.ISO20022_PAIN_01Ver3.*.xml

fi
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many flag files do you have?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, you want to pass the flag file that corresponds to a data file only if it exists, this code will do the job:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Change to bash if the .env file has bashisms

. /pbapps/pbmis/apps/apps_st/appl/APPSpbmis_ennycebs02.env

basedir=/misc/pbmis/output

for data in "$basedir/WSPGLOBAL.PAYMENTS.ISO20022_PAIN_01Ver3."*.xml; do
    without_ext="${data%%.xml}" # Remove extension
    flagnum="${without_ext##*.}" # Extract after '.' (Represents the number part)
    flagfile="$basedir/SendPaysource.$flagnum"

    # Check if the corresponding flag file exists
    [ -e "$flagfile" ] && {
        gpg --always-trust --no-tty -se --passphrase xxxxxxxxx -r xxxxx.xxxxx.com "$data"
    }
done
```

Comment: That work perfectly. Thank you.